# $E[Y|X]$ and $var[Y|X]$

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

Choose a number $X$ from the set ${(1,2,3)}$ uniformly at random. Then toss a fair coin $X$ times and with $Y$ denote the number of heads you see.

(i) Compute $E[Y|X]$ and var$[Y|X]$
(ii) Compute $E[Y]$ and var$[Y]$

(i) $$P(X=1)=\frac{1}{3},P(X=2)=\frac{1}{3},P(X=3)=\frac{1}{3}$$
Thus $E[X]=2$ and var$[X]=\frac{2}{3}.$

Using this, we can compute $E[Y|X=1],E[Y|X=2],E[Y|X=3]$. Comptuting this yields, $\frac{1}{2},1$ and $\frac{3}{2} $ respectively.

$$E[Y|X]=\frac{1}{2}X$$
$$var[Y|X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=\frac{1}{2}X-\frac{1}{4}X^2$$
(ii) $$E[Y]=E[E[Y|X]]=E[\frac{1}{2}X]=\frac{1}{2}E[X]=\frac{1}{2}(2)=1$$
$$var(Y)=var[E[Y|X]]+E[var[Y|X]]=var(\frac{1}{2}X)+E(\frac{1}{2}X-\frac{1}{4}X^2)=\frac{1}{4}var(X)+\frac{1}{2}E(X)-\frac{1}{4}E(X^2)=1/4(2/3)+1/2(2)-(1/4)(14/3)=0 $$

Comment: Aren't you worried that you found a variance 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By computing $E(Y|X=1)=1/2,$ $E(Y|X=2)=1,$ etc you *have* computed $E(Y|X).$ You can write the answer more succinctly as $E(Y|X) = X/2.$

You don't necessarily need any information on the distribution of $X$ to compute $E(Y|X)$ or $\mathrm{Var}(Y|X)$ You are conditioning on $X,$ i.e. assuming $X$ is known. However, it will be important when you compute $E(Y)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y).$

So you can compute the conditional variance in the same spirit as you got the conditional expectation. Assume $X$ is known and compute what the variance of $Y$ would be. Since the variance of the number of heads from $X$ coin flips is $X/4$, you have $\mathrm{Var}(Y|X) = X/4.$

You are correct that in order to get $E(Y)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(Y)$ you need to apply the law of total expectation and total variance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you perhaps elaborate as to how you obtained $X/2$, I am not seeing as to how to simplify my answer to your's. Also, I do not fully understand why you say that $X$ is "known." Is it because we know that each event has probability of 1/3 and so we say that it is known?

Comment: @thisisme How did you get $E(Y|X=1) = 1/2$ $E(Y|X=2) = 1$ and $E(Y|X=3) = 3/2$ ? You see how $X/2$ fits every one of those? $X$ is not known, but when you compute a conditional quantity given $X$, one way to look at this is that you are *assuming* $X$ is known and then computing the quantity in terms of the 'known' value of $X$.

Comment: I now see $X/2$ and understand the assumption. The way I went about computing the three expectations was by creating 3 pmf tables for each X value. I was wondering if the following method is also valid? Is it correct to assume $X/2$ for $E[Y|X]$ without computing the pmfs, since $X$ is treated as known here and the probability of the random variable $Y$ is $1/2$. Essentially we are doing $E[Y|X]=E[Y]E[X]$ i.e.  $1/2(1), 1/2(2) ,1/2(3)$

Comment: Correction to the above I meant $ E[Y|X]=E[Y] X$ instead of  $E[Y|X]=E[Y]E[X]$. Also could you please let me know if I did the remaining portion correctly? I added it to the initial post.

Comment: @thisisme. No. First off $E(Y)=1$ not $1/2.$ Moreover the formula $E(Y|X)= E(Y)X$ makes no sense.

Comment: @thisisme $X$ is the number of coinfilips. $Y$ is the number of heads. If the number of coinflips is fixed, the average number of heads is the number of coinflips over 2. Thus the average number of heads given the number of coinflips is the number of coinflips over 2. This is what $E(Y|X) = X/2$ means. Now if you want $E(Y)$, the average number of heads. Then you also need to average over the random number of coinflips (i.e. $X$) and get $E(Y) = (1/2)(1/3) + (1)(1/3) + (3/2)(1/3).$ Since the # of flips is 1 2 or 3 with equal prob.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, thank you. I noticed that instead of computing E(Y) using law of iterated expectation, intuitively, your method also makes sense. Also, are my solutions of variances correct?

Comment: @thisisme I did use the law of iterated expectation (although I said intuitively what we were doing when we used it). $E(Y) = E(E(Y|X)) = E(X/2) = (1/2)(1/3) + (2/2)(1/3) + (3/2)(1/3)$ (where the computation of $E(X/2)$ 
 is from the distribution of $X$: $P(X=1) = P(X=2) = P(X=3) = 1/3$)

Answer (score 0):

We know that the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ is binomial, with trial amount $X$ and success rate $1/2$. $$Y\mid X ~\sim~\mathcal{Bin}(X,1/2)$$

This tells us the conditional expectation and variance.$$\mathsf E(Y\mid X) ~=~ X\cdot\tfrac 12 \qquad\quad\\\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X) ~=~ X\cdot \tfrac 12\cdot (1-\tfrac 12)$$

(The result is well known, however, if you wish to you may arrive at this from the fact that $Y$ is the sum of successes in $X$ from a series of independent Bernoulli trials $\{Y_k\}$, with identical success rate $1/2$.   Then the Linearity of Expectation and Bilinearity of Variance state: $\mathsf E(Y\mid X) ~=~ \sum_{k=1}^X \mathsf E(Y_k)$ and $\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X)~=~\sum_{k=1}^X\mathsf {Var}(Y_k)$.)

Then we may use the Laws of Total Expectation and Variance:$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y)~&=~\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X)) \\[1ex] &=~ \tfrac 12\mathsf E(X)\\[1ex] &~~\vdots\\[5ex]\mathsf{Var}(Y)~&=~\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(Y\mid X))+\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))\\[1ex] &=~\tfrac 14 \mathsf E(X)+\tfrac 12^2~\mathsf{Var}(X)\\[1ex] &~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Since you know that $X$ is uniform discrete over the support $\{1,2,3\}$ you may complete.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand all of the work. But suppose you didn't know that the Var of a binomial is np(1-p). Would you mind showing how you would arrive to it? I attempted to solve it above, but I know that I did it incorrectly.

Comment: It's right there.  All you need to find is the variance of the independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trials.  $$\mathsf{Var}(Y_k) ~{=~ \mathsf E(Y_k^2)-\mathsf E(Y_k)^2 \\=~ 1^2\cdot \tfrac 12 - {\big(1\cdot\tfrac 12\big)}^2}$$

Comment: Thank you, but I was referring to the conditional variance $var(Y|X)$, for some reason I am having a difficulty obtaining it.

Comment: It is, as stated above: $\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X) ~{=~ \mathsf{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^X Y_k\mid X) \\=~ X\,\mathsf{Var}(Y_1)}$ Due to Bilinearity of Covariance, and the IID distribution of $\{Y_k\}$

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!